# Tips for mobile product Carousel for gallery of a single product, or should I use it at all?

Tags: e-commerce, carousel, product

Tips for mobile product Carousel, or should I use it at all?

Read an [article](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-carousels/?fbclid=IwAR0Rs0uuBS3UGHIjDPYS1aHkgEHlV43V2_4kdrA_zYLYQBHKUTg6ZUI_m7o) of NNP, saying the study suggests carousels on mobile have low discoverability.

However, this study seems to focus on the home page, my intuition tells me this might not be true on a single product page using a carousel for product images on mobile since people are used to using carousel on product pages.

How's the mobile product carousels perform on your websites? Any tips for mobile product carousel designs?

Also, what would you recommend as an alternative for a single product gallery that showcases the pictures of one product on a product page like the [following link](https://www.jcrew.com/p/mens_category/shirts/classicfitshirts/shortsleeve-slub-cotton-shirt-in-flower-print/AI847?color_name=roya-flower-navy-orange&fbclid=IwAR1P4jY7WA8g1zYNqpqS-5wWo5k1K8KtGTcF0gYqFIMJ9ahdFN_FIRnoiiA)? (please use mobile or dev tool mobile simulator)

Especially for mobile with limited screen space, are there better solutions?

Let me know your thought, experience or if you read any quantitative research about this.

Comment: The NNP study https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-carousels/?fbclid=IwAR0Rs0uuBS3UGHIjDPYS1aHkgEHlV43V2_4kdrA_zYLYQBHKUTg6ZUI_m7o

Comment: I'd apply the NNG guidelines to all pages.

Answer (score 1):

From my research, I saw some websites **hide** the carousel navigation buttons when displaying a **single** image.
Others (Realtor) display only one image and use a link to open the rest in a gallery.

> limited screen space, are there better solutions?

So far dots are the best solution for saving space in mobile.